# React Link Not Working With Button Placement

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So Currently I have my Button & Link set up in react like this

```
<NavLink to="/register">
  <NavBtnLink>Register Now</NavBtnLink>
</NavLink>
```

My Link from React-Router-Dom is named as NavLink
Putting my Link outside of the button does not route to anything

If i set it up like this it works

```
<NavBtnLink>
  <NavLink to="/register">Register Now</NavLink>
</NavBtnLink>
```

Cant seem to figure out why it wont work when placed outside so it covers the whole button when you click
to route to /register

Heres a screenshot as well

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaBhZ.png)

Comment: can you add screenshot 
it seems your code is correct

Comment: Hi Bud! Just added a screenshot on bottom of post, thank you!